# Flutter WebView soft keyboard does not hide on input blur

Tags: android, flutter, android-softkeyboard, blur

There appears to be  a long standing issue with the Flutter Webview plugin on Android - if [this discussion](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36478) is anything to go by.  I too have run into it - in a Webview dialog I have an input box which when focussed causes the Android soft keyboard to appear.  However, it does not subsequently vanish on its own when that input box looses focus - or even when it is removed from the DOM tree.  I'd be most obliged to anyone who might be able to suggest a solution.  I have tried the various ideas mentioned in that discussion including issuing `SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');` from Dart code behind.

The only other way I can think of trying is writing a little Flutter Android "plugin" that tries to hide the soft keyboard directly via the Android API which I imagine should work.  If anyone can point me to the Kotlin code required to do this I would be most grateful.

---

Here is how I am  building the app UI - the entire Widget tree

```
Route makeWebView(RouteSettings settings)
{
 return new PageRouteBuilder
 (
  pageBuilder:(BuildContext context,Animation<double> 
  animation,Animation<double> secondaryAnimation)
  {
   return SafeArea
   (
    child:Listener
    (
     child: SizedBox.expand
     (
      child:WebView
      (
       debuggingEnabled:true, 
       initialUrl:'',
       javascriptMode:JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
       onWebViewCreated:registerController,
       javascriptChannels:Set.from
      ([JavascriptChannel(name:'JSBridge',
                              onMessageReceived:handleMessage)]),
       ),
      ),
     )
    );
  });
 }
```

Comment: Please share your Widget Tree, where and how you are adding WebView to your Widget Tree...

Comment: I have modified my question.  I should mention that I start with WidgetsApp, not MaterialApp

Answer (score 3):

The fix is finally out according to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36478#issuecomment-708076118 and I have tested it. It works.

To enable the fix, you will need to enable hybrid composition, i.e.: `SurfaceAndroidWebView`.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class WebViewExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  WebViewExampleState createState() => WebViewExampleState();
}

class WebViewExampleState extends State<WebViewExample> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Enable hybrid composition.
    if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebView(
      initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
    );
  }
}
```

SurfaceAndroidWebView() requires API level 19. The plugin itself doesn't enforce the API level, so if you want to make the app available on devices running this API level or above, add the following to /android/app/build.gradle:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // Required by the Flutter WebView plugin.
        minSdkVersion 19
    }
  }
```

Link to documentation: https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter#using-hybrid-composition